# How to append and remove checkbox values to and from hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to append selected checkbox values to the hidden field.
But I am only successfull in adding only one checkbox value at this time.

Is there anyway to append selected checkbox values in hidden field.

```
    function CheckBox_Clicked(item) {


        if (item.checked == true) {

            $('#Chkboxvalue').val($(item).val());

        }
    }
```

I don't know if I could use jquery append function here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below javascript

```
function CallOnEachCheckBoxChangeEvent(){
     var selectedCheckBoxesValue = '';
        $('#DIVID').find("input:checkbox.CheckBoxClassName:checked").each(function (i, selected) {
                                                        if (selectedCheckBoxesValue.length == 0) {
                                                            selectedCheckBoxesValue += $(selected).val();
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                            selectedCheckBoxesValue += ',' + $(selected).val();
                                                        }});

         //Set the value of hiddenField selected checkboxes value 
            $(hiddenFieldValueId).val(selectedCheckBoxesValue);
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the value as well if the user deselects the value.

Comment: @alice7.. Please call the above function on change event of checkbox. This will work for you.

Comment: yes, it works like charm!!!One stupid question, how does it deselects the value from the selectedChkbox value when the user deslects.

Comment: @alice7 .. On deselect/select, we will append the selected checkboxes value (in this case it is comma separated) and assign this value to hiddenfield.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Chkboxvalue').val($('#Chkboxvalue').val()+' '+$(item).val());
```

Comment: If you uncheck some value than you can not remove it from that hidden field value by using this approach.

Comment: @alok_dida, the user didn't ask for that capability. I assumed he/she was keeping a history of which checkboxes were clicked.  So the down-vote is uncalled for.

Comment: I am sorry I should have asked what if the user deselects the checkbox.And the above line works when you select the checkbox.

Comment: @Marc .. It's default behavior of the checkbox so i think we need to take care of it.

Comment: @alok_dida, if the user is attempting to record the order/history in which items were clicked, it's not relevant to remove entries from the list.  You made an assumption.  So did I.  You took the extra step of down-voting me based on your assumption (vs. what the user already confirmed asking for).  Therefore, a comment would have been sufficient, and your down-vote action was not appropriate.

Comment: @Marc . If user is making mistake when attempting to record the order/history in which items were clicked than user is going to unclicked (which is unfortunately clicked by user) that item. Anyways as per your reputation and experience on stackoverflow site you might be right so I am withdrawing my down vote. (I tried but I am not able to withdraw it because it's locked.Sorry!!!)

Comment: @alok_dida, thank you for the follow-up. It's often tough to decipher what the asker wants vs. what he/she says they want!

Comment: @Marc .. thanks for taking my attention to it. I will take care this thing in future.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do that.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/EWsMX/